# Python Project Structure with relative imports and pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Imagine this project structure:

```
myproject
|-- mypkg1
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __main__.py
|   |-- mod1.py
|   |-- mod2.py
|   |-- standalone.py
|
|-- mypkg2
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- mod1.py
|   |-- mod2.py
|
|-- tests
|   |-- mypkg1
|   |   | --mod1_test.py
|   |-- mypkg1_mod1_test.py
|
|-- mypkg1_run.py
|-- standalone_run.py
|-- conftest.py
|-- README
```

With this contents of files:

**mypkg1.__init__.py**

```
import sys
import inspect
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.append(str((Path(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())) / '../..').resolve()))
```

**mypkg1.__main__.py**

```
from .mod1 import mod1_msg
from .mod2 import mod2_msg
from mypkg2 import mod1, mod2

def main():
    print("Hello from mypkg1 main!")
    print(mod1_msg())
    print(mod2_msg())
    print(mod1.mod1_msg())
    print(mod2.mod2_msg())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**mypkg1.mod1.py**

```
def mod1_msg():
    return "Hello from mypkg1.mod1!"
```

**mypkg1.mod2.py**

```
from .mod1 import mod1_msg

def mod2_msg():
    return "Hello from mypkg1.mod2 and {}".format(mod1_msg())
```

**mypkg1.standalone.py**

```
from .mod2 import mod2_msg

def main():
    print("Hello from mypkg1.standalone!")
    print(mod2_msg())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**mypkg2.__init__.py**

```
import sys
import inspect
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.append(str((Path(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())) / '../..').resolve()))
```

**mypkg2.mod1.py**

```
def mod1_msg():
    return "Hello from mypkg2.mod1!"
```

**mypkg2.mod2.py**

```
from .mod1 import mod1_msg

def mod2_msg():
    return "Hello from mypkg2.mod2 and {}".format(mod1_msg())
```

**tests.mypkg1.mod1_test.py** and **tests.mypkg1_mod1_test.py**

```
from mypkg1.mod1 import mod1_msg

def test_mod1():
    assert mod1_msg() == "Hello from mypkg1.mod1!"
```

**mypkg1_run.py**

```
from mypkg1.__main__ import main  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**standalone_run.py**

```
from mypkg1.standalone import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**General repository requirements**

1. The mypkg1 can use scripts from mypkg2.
2. The mypkg1 should be runnable as standalone package.
3. Pytest is used for testing.

**Required usage behaviour**

1. Run the package from the myrepo directory: python -m mypkg1
2. Run the package from outside the myrepo directory: python -m [some path].myrepo.mypkg1
3. Run the standalone package script from the myrepo directory: python -m mypkg1.standalone
4. Run the standalone package script from the outside myrepo directory: python -m [some path].myrepo.mypkg1.standalone

**Required testing behaviour**

1. Call pytest from the myrepo directory should collect and run all tests from 
   the test folder
2. The mypkg1_mod1_test.py and mod1_test.py should be runnable from its parent directory
3. The mypkg1_mod1_test.py and mod1_test.py should be runnable from any external directories

**Conclusions**

1. Relative imports is needed due to required running package from a path that is outside myrepo.
2. This line is necessary to finding siblings packages
   `sys.path.append(str((Path(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())) / '../..').resolve()))`

And finally my **Questions**

1. Is there any way to make the standalone.py be runnable as a script from its package in this project structure? Like double click on the script file. When I run standalone like this I get this error:
   `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.mod2'; '__main__' is not a package`
   This error is caused by relative imports within package.
2. Is there any antipatern in my project/package structure convention?
3. Is there any things that should be corrected or improved?

Comment: This is a great question and I have been wondering similar. I will print and ponder. If I have any thoughts will share! Thank you for the nice and clear layout of the problem.